# Is there a battery complexity similar to how there is time complexity and space complexity?

Tags: complexity

Understood that for all these ways of measuring the time and space is dependant on the users hardware, I was wondering is there is a similar way to calculate the battery usage of a program over `n` amount of time? Or is it **completely** dependant on the hardware?

Comment: In general, the battery usage should scale proportionately to instructions. The big thing that will cause it to deviate is wireless communication, which will vary a bit based on device, locale, and operating environment.

Comment: In addition to the comment by @Telastyn, another big drain on the battery is the screen. Having the screen on all the time will drain the battery much faster than when the device is sitting idle with the screen off.

Comment: When we talk about *step complexity*, *time complexity*, or *space complexity*, we *always* talk about it relative to a *machine model* and a *cost model*. So, before we can really talk about *energy complexity* or *battery complexity*, you first need to define your machine model and your cost model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Step complexity* is usually based on the assumption that every operation takes an amount of time bounded by a constant. Sometimes the assumption is stronger, namely that every operation takes roughly the same, constant, amount of time.

If we make a similar assumption, namely that every operation takes an amount of *energy* bounded by a constant, then "energy complexity" is exactly the same as step complexity.

However, note that talking about algorithmic complexity in a vacuum makes no sense. When we talk about *step complexity*, *time complexity*, or *space complexity*, we *always* talk about it relative to a *machine model* and a *cost model*. So, before we can really talk about *energy complexity* or *battery complexity*, you first need to define your machine model and your cost model.

Just as an example: copying a list of length n takes Θ(n) steps in the RAM model but Θ(n²) in the Turing Machine model.